# Agrupar y sumar en mysql. para crear un reporte

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Tengo la siguiente tabla y quiero Agrupar y sumar** como en el siguiente ejemplo que les pongo.

Les comento que esta tabla la voy a tener en una vista ya que es el resultado de varias tablas.=)

### [image: Tengo esta tabla]

---

**RESULTADO DESEADO...**

---

[image: Resultado deseado]
No sé como sumar y agrupar al mismo tiempo.

**esto lo meteré en una vista.**

```
SELECT cod_prod,tipo_mesualidad,precio_servicio, fecha_Recibo, nivel_al 
FROM detarecibos as D 
INNER JOIN recibo as R ON D.id_Reci=R.cod_Recibo 
INNER JOIN alumnos as A ON R.id_alumnPago=A.id_al 
WHERE fecha_Recibo='2018-01-21'
```

La verdad quiero hacerlo limpio para no confundirme y empezar una nueva consulta desde la vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si es esto lo que buscas.. Con esta consulta sacas el resultado que indicas en tu pregunta:

```
SELECT
nivel_al, SUM(cant) AS cant, tipo_mensualidad, SUM(precio_servicio) AS precio_servicio
FROM detallerecibos
GROUP BY nivel_al,tipo_mensualidad
```

Comment: gracias lo revisaré y te comento en un momento.

Comment: gracias irene. propodre otra pegunta como hacer para obtener de dos tablas. listar los que no se encontraron en ambas.eje.  tabla 1. alumnos inscritos. tabla dos alumnos ya pagaron. =pendientes de pago. Bendiciones.

Comment: Sólo tendrías que hacer un NOT IN:

`SELECT *
FROM mva_alumnos
WHERE id_al NOT IN(SELECT id_alumnPago FROM mva_recibo)`

Comment: gracias gracias